# Flutter | Unable to save a custom model List to shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Issue :

Unable to save custom model data to a list as Shared preferences.

**Cart** Model :

```
Cart Class{
        
      String id;
      Product product;
      String product_name;
      double quantity;
      String userId;
    
      Cart();
    
      Map toMap() {

        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        map['product_name'] = product.name;
        map["id"] = id;
        map["quantity"] = quantity;          
        map["user_id"] = userId;
        return map;
      }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    :
    :
    List<Cart> catchedCart = new List(2000);  //initialization
    :
    :
    updateSharedListCart(cartToBePassed, position)  // cartToBePassed is an object of type Cart & 
                                                    //  position where to be added
    :
    :
    :
    updateSharedListCart(Cart cartToAppendDelete, int pos) async {
    
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setStringList("catchedCart[pos]", cartToAppendDelete);
              setState(() {
                   catchedCart[pos]= prefs.getString('catchedCart[pos]');
                       });
          
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      
    }
  }
```

So Flutter is returning the error : "`The argument type 'Cart' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'`"

Can someone please help with the syntax to use my custom model for setting Shared preferences ? A sample would be of great help..

Comment: you should cast your prefs.getString('catchedCart[pos]') to Card

Comment: You can store the String of the Cart class that you have by using `prefs.setStringList("catchedCart[pos]", cartToAppendDelete.toString());`, but you will need a way to read the stored string. You can create a function like `fromString` in your cart class to read it in the `setState` call.